# Copy Folder Contents to Parent Directory in Rake (on Windows)

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a set of files in a folder `../SomeFolder/AndAnother/dist`

the dist folder contains a bunch of files and folders that I want to move up a level in a Rake task.

So

`../SomeFolder/AndAnother/dist/subFolder/a.txt` becomes `../SomeFolder/AndAnother/subFolder/a.txt`

I can do this on linux by

```
task :lift_to_parent do
  sh('mv', '../SomeFolder/AndAnother/dist/*', '../SomeFolder/AndAnother')
end
```

but this Rake task also runs on Windows and on that OS i get `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal`

I'm hoping that `FileUtils.mv` will work on both linux and windows...

but if I

```
task :lift_to_parent do
  FileUtils.mv '../SomeFolder/AndAnother/dist', '../SomeFolder/AndAnother', :force => true
end
```

I get `ArgumentError: same file: ../SomeFolder/AndAnother/dist and ../SomeFolder/AndAnother/dist` so I'm clearly missing something to allow `FileUtils.mv` to copy up a level (or going about this the wrong way)

So, how do I fix my FileUtils version or otherwise use a Rake task to copy a folder structure to its parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up doing this

```
task : lift_to_parent do
  copied_by_jenkins = '../SomeFolder/AndAnother/dist'
  copy_pattern = "#{copied_by_jenkins}/**/*"
  target_directory = '../SomeFolder/AndAnother/Public'

  next unless File.exists? copied_by_jenkins

  FileList[copy_pattern].each do |file|
    file_path = File.dirname(file).sub! copied_by_jenkins, ''
    file_name = File.basename(file)
    target_directory = File.join(target_directory, file_path)
    destination = File.join(target_directory, file_name)

    FileUtils.mkdir_p target_directory
    FileUtils.copy_file(file, destination) unless File.directory? file
  end

  FileUtils.remove copied_by_jenkins
end
```

but that seems like a lot of the typing to achieve my goal